# Detect key(s) held down in another process

Tags: delphi, process, keyboard

I have a Delphi 2007 Win32 executable which sends keystrokes to other applications. My app is invoked from within these target applications by a hotkey like F11 or Shift+F11.

I want users to be able to hold down a key to abort the keystroke sending (say, if they realize they invoked my app in the wrong location). I had thought Shift, Ctrl, and Alt were good candidates because, alone, those key presses aren't likely to disrupt anything in the target application. (Escape, for instance, is a bad choice, as it might cause the target application to close one or more windows.)

I wrote the function farther below and call it periodically as follows, while sending keystrokes with the intent of detecting keys held down.

```
if wsAnyKeysDownInWindow( TgtWindow, [VK_Escape, VK_Menu{Alt}, VK_Control, VK_Shift] ) then 
  Abort;
```

Problem is, my app sends keystroke combinations like Shift+Tab and Ctrl+Home, which (I think) makes this approach fail--it *always* detects a down state for Shift and/or Ctrl. (I also tried a similar function which called SetKeyboardState just prior to beginning to send keystrokes, to set the key states' high-order (down) bit but that didn't help.)

Anyone think of a workable approach, short of hooking the keyboard?

```
function wsAnyKeysDownInWindow(Handle: HWnd; VKeys: array of byte): boolean;
{ Checks whether each of the VKeys set of virtual keys is down in Handle,
  a window created by another process. }
var
  OtherThreadID : integer;
  State: TKeyboardState;
  AKey: byte;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not IsWindow(Handle) then
    exit;
  OtherThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessID( Handle, nil);
  if AttachThreadInput( GetCurrentThreadID, OtherThreadID, True ) then try
    GetKeyboardState(State);
    for AKey in VKeys do
      if (State[AKey] and 128) <> 0 then begin  //If high-order bit is set, key is down
        Result := True;
        exit;
      end;
  finally
    AttachThreadInput( GetCurrentThreadID, OtherThreadID, False );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `SetKeyboardState` wouldn't work cross thread/process, but you might try searching on `AttachThreadInput`.

Comment: Sertac: That is how I used SetKeyboardState--I called AttachThreadInput, then GetKeyboardState to get the target process' current states, reset the high-order (down) bits in the state array for those selected virtual keys, then called SetKeyboardState. But my later calls to the function shown above found keys in the down state...which I assumed was from the keystrokes I sent. (I had also tried a PeekMessage() loop before sending keystrokes to remove any superfluous keystrokes from the queue, but that didn't work either.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Scroll Lock` for this. It is rarely used (only of Excel comes to my mind), and you will have even visual indicator if keys are being sent or not.

BTW, `Alt` is not a good choice for another reason - it invokes the main menu in an application (if there is one, of course).

Comment: Scroll Lock might be OK except most users don't intuitively know where it is on the keyboard! I was looking to support a less-obscure key(s). And yes, I had realized Alt is a poor choice, for the reason you give.

Comment: I don't think Scroll Lock is obscure. Less "obscure" keys are those which are frequently used, so this rules them out.

Another good thing with Scroll Lock is `on`/`off` key, and usually there is a LED indicator which will visually indicate the state.